# Style jQuery UI slider like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, styles

I need to make the slider look like this:

[image: Slider design]

As you can see, there is a limit (dark line) in the full capacity (light line).

I have this code so far:

```
<p>
  <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

---

```
var myMax = 500;
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 300,
    min: 1,
    max: 2000,
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $( "#amount" ).val(ui.value);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.value > myMax) {
            return false;
            ui.value = myMax;
        }
        $( "#amount" ).val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyadaro/vp00n013/

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? The slider is built with HTML and CSS, just style it how you would any other element

Comment: @jacob-gray What I'm asking is if it's possible to make that "limit" line (the dark one) in the slider.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure there are other jQuery plugins to accomplish this, here's a quick hack using your code.

First, create another `<div>` within your slider:

```
   <div id="slider">
       <div id="limit"></div>
   </div>
```

Next, have JS calculate the percentage of `myMax`, and use a bit of jQuery to set the width of `#limit` to the appropriate percentage.

```
var myMax = 500;
var max = 2000;
var limit = $("#limit");
limit.css("width", (myMax/max)*100+"%" )
```

Finally, style the `#limit`, for example:

```
#slider {
position: relative;
}
#limit {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
background: #afb1b2;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fd29cvb4/2/) demonstrating the hack.

Comment: Totally looks like what I need. I'm gonna put styles on it, I'll be back.